# cordova-sqlite-storage duplicating when inserting into database

Tags: cordova, plugins, cordova-sqlite-storage

I am new to using the [cordova-sqlite-storage plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) and have been using a modified version of [this CRUD tutorial](http://www.developerin.net/a/75-Code-Snippet/115-CRUD-Operation-using-Phonegap-and-SQLite) in my App. The database is created and opens and the Table is created successfully but when I insert one item, it is duplicated a number of times, rather than just entered once. All the duplicated items have unique Id's. I have tried modifying it many ways but I'm stuck. I can't figure out why it is adding so many on insert. I appreciate any help!

Here is my code (apologize if it is a bit long):

```
var myDB;
var vetDrugsId = 0;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

 myDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "my.db", iosDatabaseLocation: 'Documents' });
    CreateDB();
    RefreshDrugs();

 }

 // Create Registration table in Sql Lite DB.
 function CreateDB() {
    myDB.transaction(function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vetDrugs (Id integer primary key, title text, desc text, conc integer, dose integer, minimum integer, maximum integer)', [],
            function (tx, result) {
                console.log("Table created successfully");
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("Error occurred while creating the table.");
            });
    });
}

//Insert New Details (into SQLite Database)
   $(document).on('click touchstart','#insert',function () {
 var title=$("#title").val();
 var desc=$("#desc").val();
 var conc=parseInt($("#conc").val());
 var dose=parseInt($("#dose").val());
 var minimum=parseInt($("#minimum").val());
 var maximum=parseInt($("#maximum").val());

 myDB.transaction(function (transaction) {
        if (vetDrugsId > 0) {
            myDB.transaction(function (transaction) {
                var executeQuery = "UPDATE vetDrugs SET title=?, desc=? ,conc=?, dose=?, minimum=?, maximum=? WHERE Id=?";
                  transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, [title,desc,conc,dose,minimum,maximum,vetDrugsId],
                  //On Success
                  function (tx, result) {

                 RefreshDrugs();
                  ClearControl();
              $('#title,#desc,#conc,#dose,#minimum,#maximum').removeClass('error-border');
                       toastUpdate.open();
                  },
                  function (error) {
                      alert('Details not updated');
                  });
            });
        }
        else {

            var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO vetDrugs (title, desc, conc, dose, minimum, maximum) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 
             transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, [title,desc,conc,dose,minimum,maximum]
                , function (tx, result) {

               RefreshDrugs();
                  ClearControl();

            $('#title,#desc,#conc,#dose,#minimum,#maximum').removeClass('error-border');
                    //alert('Inserted successfully');
                    toastAdd.open();
                },
                function (error) {
                    //alert('Details not Inserted');
                    toastAddError.open();
                });
        }
    });
});

// Load Data in Table from SQLite Database.
function RefreshDrugs() {
    $("#TableData").html("");
    myDB.transaction(function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM vetDrugs', [], function (tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length, i;
            $("#rowCount").html(len);
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

$('#TableData').append('<div class="table-row"><div class="column index hidden-print checkbox-cell"><a class="link actions-open" href="#" data-actions=".my-actions'+results.rows.item(i).Id+'"><i class="far fa-cog fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a><div class="actions-modal my-actions'+results.rows.item(i).Id+'"><div class="list"><ul><li><a href="#" class="edit list-button actions-close" id="edit_'+results.rows.item(i).Id+'"><i class="far fa-pencil fa-fw fa-lg"></i> Edit Drug</a></li><li><a id="delete_'+results.rows.item(i).Id+'" class="delete list-button actions-close" href="#" data-id="'+results.rows.item(i).Id+'"><i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-fw fa-lg"></i> Delete Drug</a></li><li><a class="btnCancel list-button actions-close" href="#"><i class="far fa-ban fa-fw fa-lg"></i> Cancel</a></li></ul></div></div></div><div class="wrapper attributes"><div class="wrapper drugName-concentration-condition-range"><div class="wrapper drugName-concentration"><div class="column drugName"><span class="drugTitle">'+results.rows.item(i).title+'</span>  <p class="subtitle">'+results.rows.item(i).conc+' mg/ml</p> </div></div><div class="wrapper condition-range"><div class="column range">'+results.rows.item(i).desc+'</div></div></div></div><div class="wrapper results"><div class="column result"><input class="form-control form-control-sm drug" data-appendDose=" mg" data-appendVol=" ml" data-mg="#'+results.rows.item(i).Id+'mg" data-ml="#'+results.rows.item(i).Id+'ml" name="'+results.rows.item(i).Id+'name" type="number" data-conc="'+results.rows.item(i).conc+'" data-min="'+results.rows.item(i).minimum+'" data-max="'+results.rows.item(i).maximum+'" data-step="0.1" data-postfix="mg/kg" data-decimal="2" data-value="'+results.rows.item(i).dose+'"  value="'+results.rows.item(i).dose+'" ><span class="error-message"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-sm fa-fw hidden-print" data-fa-transform="up-2"></i> Above Range</span></div><div class="column result"><span class="dosage bg-color-blue color-white" id="'+results.rows.item(i).Id+'mg" ></span></div><div class="column result"><span class="vol bg-color-green color-white" id="'+results.rows.item(i).Id+'ml" ></span></div></div></div>');

            }
        }, null);
    });

  }

   // Get and Set Current Selected data.
    $(document).on('click touchstart', '.edit', function () {
     app.accordion.open("#panel10");
     var delString = this.id;

    var splitId = delString.split("_");
    var curId = splitId[1];
    //alert(curId);

    vetDrugsId = parseInt(curId);

    if (vetDrugsId > 0) {
        myDB.transaction(function (transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM vetDrugs  where Id=?', [vetDrugsId], function (tx, results) {
                var len = results.rows.length, i;

                if (len > 0) {
 $("#title").val(results.rows.item(0).title);
 $("#desc").val(results.rows.item(0).desc);
 $("#conc").val(results.rows.item(0).conc);
 $("#dose").val(results.rows.item(0).dose);
 $("#minimum").val(results.rows.item(0).minimum);
 $("#maximum").val(results.rows.item(0).maximum);
   $('#title,#desc,#conc,#dose,#minimum,#maximum').addClass('error-border');

                }
                else {
                       $('#title,#desc,#conc,#dose,#minimum,#maximum').removeClass('error-border');
                    ClearControl();
                }
            }, null);
        });
    }

});

// Cancel the current Operation.
$(".btnCancel").on('click touchstart',function ()  {
    ClearControl();
 });

 // Clear Control
  function ClearControl() {
   vetDrugsId = 0;
    $("#title").val('');$("#desc").val('');  $("#conc").val(''); $("#dose").val('');
    $("#minimum").val(''); $("#maximum").val('');
        $('#title,#desc,#conc,#dose,#minimum,#maximum').removeClass('error-border');

}

   //Delete Selected Registration data from SQLite Database.
    $(document).on('click touchstart', '.delete', function () {

    if (confirm("Do you want to delete Drug?")) {
  var delString = this.id;

    var splitId = delString.split("_");
    var curId = splitId[1];
    //alert(curId);
    id = parseInt(curId);
        //var ID = this.id;
        //var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        myDB.transaction(function (transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql("DELETE FROM vetDrugs where Id=?", [id],
              //Success
              function (tx, result) {
                alert('Deleted successfully');  
                ClearControl();
        RefreshDrugs();
              },
              //Error
              function (error) { alert('Data not deleted.'); });
        });

    }

});


  $(document).on('click touchstart','#DropTable',function () {

   if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete everything?")) {
myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
    //var executeQuery = "DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS myDrugs";
    //transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, [],
      transaction.executeSql("DELETE FROM vetDrugs", [],
        function(tx, result) {alert('Data deleted successfully.');
        RefreshDrugs();

      },
        function(error){alert('Error occurred while deleting the table.');}
    );
 });

}

});
```

Comment: If you put a console log on the click/touchstart functions, how many times is it printed? I think your problem is there and not in the plugin code

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!